We've passed the 500+ Visits per day statistic (January 2013)
The following are just a few observations about our Area 51 site statistics.

I have just noticed that our visits per day are now above  500 per day.
This is enough to be classified as "okay".  
In  possibly related news, we have our first famous question with 10,000+ page views. These page views were amassed in around 90 days. So it's interesting to think about how particular popular questions are driving a lot of our search traffic (e.g., perhaps 100+ visits per day for this one question).
The questions per day count has dropped over the Christmas/New Year holiday period. Hopefully this comes back up soon to at least the 2+ zone.
Our percentage answered is only just above 80%.



Still, this is growth and progress! Yay!

Great, however the greatest challenge as I see would be the mass of the new questions. Without it the whole site would be as good to be wikipedised... Hope the questions will not simply end such way

There were points later last year that we were hovering close to three questions per day. In particular, I'd  like to see some more questions coming from research students and  academics. However, it seems that community building takes time.

I wonder why the questions per day is so low. Mind-related communities tend to have plenty of questions and few answers.

@zodium It often hovers around the 2 questions per day mark, but of course that's still not as high as we would like. There's also a degree of quality control on the site in terms of questions. But if you have any ideas for increasing the size of the community and the questions, that would be great.

@JeromyAnglim I posted my thoughts over here: link
